# How to concat a pandas dataframe correctly?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following function:

```py
def assign_flag(
    delta_list, one_lower_bound, one_upper_bound, two_upper_bound, two_lower_bound
):
    flag_1 = [
        np.where(
            (np.array(delta_list) > np.array(one_lower_bound))
            & (np.array(delta_list) < np.array(one_upper_bound)),
            0,
            1,
        )
    ]
    flag_2 = [
        np.where(
            (np.array(delta_list) > np.array(two_lower_bound))
            & (np.array(delta_list) < np.array(two_upper_bound)),
            0,
            1,
        )
    ]

    return flag_1, flag_2
```

And this code:

```py
parent_df_1 = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=test_delta_df.drop(columns=["cycle_end_date", "prime_tagging"]).columns
)
parent_df_2 = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=test_delta_df.drop(columns=["cycle_end_date", "prime_tagging"]).columns
)
for date in test_delta_df["cycle_end_date"].unique():
    print(date)
    delta_list = [
        test_delta_df[
            (test_delta_df.cycle_end_date == date)
            & (test_delta_df.prime_tagging == "New")
        ].drop(columns=["cycle_end_date", "prime_tagging"])
    ]
    flag_1, flag_2 = assign_flag(
        delta_list, one_lower_bound, one_upper_bound, two_upper_bound, two_lower_bound
    )
    flag_1_df = pd.DataFrame(
        [flag_1],
        columns=test_delta_df.drop(columns=["cycle_end_date", "prime_tagging"]).colmuns,
    )
    parent_df = pd.concat([flag_1_df, parent_df_1])
    flag_2_df = pd.DataFrame([flag_1, parent_df_2])

one_lower_bound = list(flag_tbl_2.iloc[3])
one_upper_bound = list(flag_tbl_2.iloc[2])
two_upper_bound = list(flag_tbl_2.iloc[4])
two_lower_bound = list(flag_tbl_2.iloc[5])
```

My flag_tbl looks like: this is my flag tbl, it also has cycle_end_date and prime_tagging as last two columns
[image]

My test_delta_df : it does not have cycle_end_date at the end
[image]

I basically want to calculate for each delta in my test_delta_df, I want to create a flag
which I have defined in assign_flag function above.

When I am executing I am getting the following error:

```
KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

and `KeyError:0`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is possible convert DataFrames to text and test it raise same error? [Why don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Can you include the full traceback?